# how to change input text into url link

Tags: php, html, forms, whatsapp

I have four input texts and one submit button 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sghdl.png)

what I want is for the results of the input text to turn into a link that I use as a whatsapp message like this.

`https://wa.me/628123456789?text=Hai%20My%20Name%20Andi`

what should i do?
this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- https://wa.me/628123456789?text=textInput1%20textInput2%20textInput3%20textInput4 -->
    <form action="https://wa.me/628123456789?text=textInput1%20textInput2%20textInput3%20textInput4" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="textInput1" id="textInput1" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="textInput2" id="textInput2" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="textInput3" id="textInput3" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="textInput4" id="textInput4" ><br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

  <?php 
      //target url --> https://wa.me/628123456789?text=textInput1%20textInput2%20textInput3%20textInput4
  $url = null;
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $textInput1 = $_POST['textInput1'];
    $textInput2 = $_POST['textInput2'];
    $textInput3 = $_POST['textInput3'];
    $textInput4 = $_POST['textInput4'];
    $url = "https://wa.me/628123456789?text=".$textInput1." ".$textInput2." ".$textInput3." ".$textInput4;
  }
   ?>

</body>
</html>
```

this is var_dump result for my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxHwn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set your form to method post, see my code below. Add name attributes to your inputs fields and submit button so you can retrieve their values through http post. Then check to see if the submit button has been posted using `isset($_POST['submit'])`. If isset, we assign the values of your input fields to variables in order to recreate the urls post key/value pairs.

***IMPORTANT NOTE:*** I am not covering cleaning of your input fields make sure to read up on proper cleaning of inputs depending on what you are allowing to be processed by the back-end code in order to recreate your url.

```
<form action="/https://wa.me/628123456789?text=textInput1%20textInput2%20textInput3%20textInput4" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="textInput1" id="textInput1" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="textInput2" id="textInput2" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="textInput3" id="textInput3" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="textInput4" id="textInput4" ><br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
//target url --> https://wa.me/628123456789?text=textInput1%20textInput2%20textInput3%20textInput4
$url = null;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $textInput1 = $_POST['textInput1'];
  $textInput2 = $_POST['textInput2'];
  $textInput3 = $_POST['textInput3'];
  $textInput4 = $_POST['textInput4'];
  $url = "https://wa.me/628123456789?text=".$textInput1." ".$textInput2." ".$textInput3." ".$textInput4;
}
```

**Example OUTPUT**. Simply outputting the url within an html page in example:

[image]

In your html simply echo out the variable `$url`. it will only display in your code when it is actually set. `<?=$url?>` or `<?php echo $url;?>`

**NOTE:** If you are trying to place the link into your action attribute of your form prior to submitting the page so that the values set in the input fields are a part of the forms action, you will need to get the values before submitting the page by using JS or JQuery and getting the values of the inputs on change or something of that nature, then build the url in js/jquery then set your forms attribute `action` using JS/Jquery.

**EDIT:** ***I want the result of the input text to be a whatsapp message, so it will be placed in the url link. I have updated my post***

Okay, to redirect user once the form is filled out and you have sanitized your inputs, set the url in your a `header()` function and redirect your user to the desired url.

*Make sure you *remove the **action** attribute from your form* as you will be redirecting using the php `header()` function instead.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // I am using filter_var(FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) in this example. 
    $textInput1 = filter_var ( $_POST['textInput1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $textInput2 = filter_var ( $_POST['textInput2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $textInput3 = filter_var ( $_POST['textInput3'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $textInput4 = filter_var ( $_POST['textInput4'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    // make sure to test this url by echoing it out before you run the header redirect. 
    $url = urlencode("https://wa.me/628123456789?text=".$textInput1." ".$textInput2." ".$textInput3." ".$textInput4);
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
}
```

Using a conditional with a foreach loop with header to contruct url from post values:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $url = "https://wa.me/628123456789?text="; // declare the core of your url without the post values  
  $i = 1; // increment 
  $k = 0; // key value for $inputs
  $userinput = ''; // empty variable to hold user inputs for encoding
  $num = count($_POST) - 1;  // count the number of items in the array to properly format spaces in url string subtract one for submit button 
  foreach($_POST as $value){ // run a foreach loop on the $_POST
    if($value !== "Submit"){ // we remove the submit post value from our array by omitting it using does not equal    
      $inputs[] = filter_var ( $value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // create a new array and push values into it
      if($i < $num){ // all but last iterations will produce the space
        $url .= $input[$k]." ";
      }else{ // last iteration will not have a space
        $url .= $input[$k]; 
      }
    }    
  }  
  $url .= urlencode($userinput);
  echo $url; // for testing purposes to make sure the string is populating the input values as you have entered them delete this line after testing. 
  //header("Location: $url"); <-- Uncomment this line to redirect
  //exit(); <-- uncomment exit() if you uncomment header() to close after redirect to make sure code stops on this page. 
}
```

Comment: I've tried the code, but what appears in the address bar doesn't match, and messages from text input can't appear
the link that appears in the address bar like this. it's not like you have, is there any mistake on me?

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=628123456789&text=textInput1%20textInput2%20textInput3%20textInput4&source=&data=

Comment: Are you trying to place that url in the action section of your form? Waht do you get when you var_dump your url string? Can you please post the result of your var_dump as well?

Comment: I want the result of the input text to be a whatsapp message, so it will be placed in the url link.
I have updated my post

Comment: Right, how are you initializing that link though? Through a header redirect or through your form action or how exactly?

Comment: so after I fill out the form then submit, it will automatically be directed to the whatsapp link and contain a message on the form, what do you think is best?

Comment: I see. You can use header() to achieve this. Just make sure to test your url before sending it. So you want `https://wa.me/628123456789?text=` then a combination of the variables that are being posted from your input forms yes?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the function urlencode() before the content:

```
 $url = urlencode("https://wa.me/628123456789?text=".$textInput1." ".$textInput2." ".$textInput3." ".$textInput4);
```

Comment: it doesn't work on me
it still 
`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=628123456789&text=textInput1%20textInput2%20textInput3%20textInput4&source=&data=` 
in link address, its not containing message that I filled in the previous form